# How to prevent a combobox from selecting an item from its list in wpf?

Tags: wpf, combobox

This combobox should display a bound value as its text, and cannot be disabled.
I just want to prevent a user from changing the displayed value.

Answer (score 8):

```
    comboBoxName.IsHitTestVisible = false;
    comboBoxName.Focusable = false;
```

Use these two line codes together.

Edit Note: Edited to solve the problem described by `skypecakes`

Comment: That doesn't do much. You can still tab to it and change the value with arrow keys, and drop down the list with F4.

Comment: `comboBoxName.IsHitTestVisible = false;
 comboBoxName.Focusable = false;` Use these two line code together. Second line will prevent you to tab to it.

Comment: @Peter This should be the accepted answer. It's the only one that does what we want without disabling (which changes the appearance). The only other way to accomplish this would be to extract and modify the template, which is best avoided and by setting these properties is in fact unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to MSDN you need

```
IsReadOnly = true;
IsEditable = false;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.isreadonly.aspx under Remarks

Edit: actually, I'm not sure any more

I suggest using a style to set ReadOnly to true on PART_EditableTextBox

Answer (score 1):

Try in
XAML

```
IsEnabled="False"
```

C#

```
YOUCOMBOBOX.IsEnabled=false;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the IsEnabled = false this should work. In your XAML it would look like this

```html
<ComboBox IsEnabled="False"></ComboBox>
```

Comment: I don't want it (or beter didn't want it, not doing wpf anymore :) ) disabled.  I just want it read-only

Answer (score -3):

Your question is unclear.

A combobox has the dependency property IsEditable and if set to false, the selected item can not be edited. This is false by default.

If you are talking about the items in the combobox popup list, then it should also be "non editable" unless you have changed the data template of your combo box to contain a list of textboxes which will cause the list to allow each item to be editable.

Comment: Even with IsEditable set to false, you can change the selection.  I want the value to be readonly.

Comment: set Readonly to True